# Assertion failure in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm getting this error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:3241
```

Two methods:

```
- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)layout {
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]) {
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImageView *backgroundView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
```

I've also checked for typos or spaces in my identifiers both in code and my Storyboard.

Comment: can you add your code for: - (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Answer (score 0):

It may be the fact you are allocating a new object in cellForItemAtIndexPath. This can be problematic if a user is scrolling through the collection view. Instead, use a for loop in viewDidLoad adding the images to an NSMutableArray, then use that array as your data source. Generally, you never want to allocate new objects in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method because it gets called so often.

EDIT: Also, what is backroundView? You're allocating a new imageView called bg, not backgroundView. You're not using the variable bg.

Comment: Ah sorry, fixed the backgroundView problem.

Comment: Check what I wrote in my first response. You can't create a new UIImageView in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own subclass of UICollectionViewCell, and add the subviews in the initWithFrame method.

That way, when you dequeue a cell that was recycled, you don't need to worry if it already has that extra view or not.